# How to decrease VB6 project startup time / Pinpointing what's taking so long

Tags: performance, vb6

There are two vb6 applications that I work with.  One of them starts up very quickly whereas the other one takes quite a long time.  I thought I would do a little analysis to find out why the one takes so long.

So I hit F8 to start at the beginning and I realize that a significant portion of that startup time is actually between the time I hit F8 and the time it highlights the very first line of code.

Which of the following is most likely causing this?

- Number of dependencies
- Having too many projects in the group project instead of referencing them as dlls
- Number of forms
- Number of objects in the startup form
- Number of objects on all forms
- What else?

And as a bonus, I would love any ideas on how to more specifically pinpoint the problem if it could be in multiple areas.

Thanks!

Edit: It seems I may have not been clear enough on exactly 'where' the slowdown is occurring.  So to make it clear I created the following procedure:

```
Sub Main()
End Sub
```

That's it, and it's in a module that contains absolutely nothing besides these two lines.  No forms are getting loaded, and while there are other modules with "Dim o as New SomeObject", I know those objects aren't getting instantiated because I know that visual basic doesn't create objects declared this way until you actually use them for the first time.

I believe I have now optimized the startup code as much as is technically possible.  Yet it still takes the same amount of time to startup.

Edit 2: I just realized that the compiled application actually starts up reasonably fast.  It's just starting it in the ide that takes so long.  However, I care a lot more about the speed for me than I do the customer cause they just start it once and leave it running all day whereas I start it a couple dozen times a day.

Comment: +1 for the question. Presumably the second possibility you mention (too many projects in startup group) is easy to test? Just open the main VBP and press F8. Sounds to me like it could simply be the amount of code in the project (or project group). I've noticed this delay when starting large projects in the IDE, and always put it down to the size of the project.

Comment: Both the fast and slow projects are full POS systems.  The fast one is way more outdated though, uses very few classes (if you can call them that), and fewer dll references.  It also has fewer lines of code, but it's still got a lot of code... so I tend to think it maybe has more to do with loading dll references.

Comment: "while there are other modules with "Dim o as New SomeObject", I know those objects aren't getting instantiated because I know that visual basic doesn't create objects declared this way until you actually use them for the first time". **According to MSDN, that isn't exactly true -- a new instance of the class is created when the Dim statement runs. Auto-instancing variables are never recommended.**

Comment: Are you looking at the MSDN for VB.net or VB6?  Try putting a breakpoint in the class initialer, autoinstance it somewhere, and tell me if it gets run immediately or when you first try to use the variable.  Then feel free to come back and tell me I was right ;)

Comment: Dim x as New SomeObject does not actually create the instance of the object. It generates code such that every time x is used, a test is done to see if the object exists, and it is created if not. That is why Dim x as New SomeObject is not recommended -- because it has to test if x has gotten created every single time x is referenced. If you do Dim x as Object : Set x = New SomeObject the object is created once and there is no test when x is referenced.

Comment: Ok that makes perfect sense, although not the same as what you put in bold in your last comment.  I tend to lean towards favoring the aesthetics of the code over speed though until there's an actual cause for being concerned about the speed.  I realize I'm often in the minority on that point, but somehow I still manage to write faster code than others around me in spite of it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How big is the project? It's probably doing an intermediate compile to p-code so it can run it.
You may be able to tweak this using the Compile settings in the Options dialog.

Comment: It's a 10+ year old Point of Sale application.  I did a very rough estimate of how big it was once.  I don't remember now but I'd say lines of code are in the 100,000ish area.  But that's everything including some stuff that's not in this group project.

All projects are set to Native with Optimize for Fast Code and Favor Pentium Pro checked.  Also allow unrounded floating point ops and Remove Safe Pentium Checks are checked in the advanced options.

Comment: +1 for that though cause I realized not all projects in the group had those options set.  They were smaller projects and it didn't change anything, and it probably won't provide a noticeable difference anywhere else either... but it still makes me happier to have them set right now :)

Comment: Note that the native/p-code and optimisations do not apply when debugging. Does F5 vs. Ctrl+F5 make a difference?

Comment: I wondered about that, although I kind of figured that was the case.  That did just cause me to realize, however, that the compiled application starts up fairly quickly and it's just starting it in the ide that takes a long time.  I don't really care about the customers though, haha, I just want it to start fast for me :)

No difference in speed between F5 and Ctrl-F5.

Comment: Maybe splitting the project into smaller components will speed up compile and IDE startup time as it has to deal with less.

Comment: Okay, so the main executeable starts up in a second and has 50k+ lines of code.  The business objects dll only has 20k- lines, but it takes 20+ revolutions of the windows 7 spinny icon.  Unfortunately of all the projects I want to have in the group that's the most important (aside from the exe).  Still, I'm glad to have narrowed it down to that and maybe I could do some fiddling around with that dll and do something good :)  Thanks for helping me think through this!

Comment: MZ-Tools has a Statistics command that will show the lines of code and comments on a per module/class basis as well as a grand total

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned that you are using Sub Main and so the delay is happening before any forms are loaded, the most likely possibility is that the problem is in the initialization routines of DLLs that you have linked in.

Every DLL exports an entry point function (usually [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) which is called right after the DLL is linked in. In VB6 this would be before `Sub Main` is executed.

It's usually very bad form for DLL authors to do anything significant at all in DllMain for precisely this reason, but many lazy DLL developers do all kinds of work in their DllMain that doesn't really have to be done until later. If you can identify the culprit and rewrite it, that'll fix your problem. If you can't rewrite it, you may at least be able to find a way to dynamically load the DLL instead of linking it.

There is one more thing that you can do to speed up launch time of any Windows application that relies on a lot of DLLs, which is to [rebase all the DLLs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/RebaseDll.aspx).

EXEs and DLLs are compiled to assume that they are going to be loaded in memory at certain starting addresses called the [Preferred Load Address](http://home.hiwaay.net/~georgech/WhitePapers/MapFiles/MapFiles.htm). For example, a DLL might contain a JMP instruction (basically a GOTO) specifying an absolute address to jump to. The DLL file itself would include a little instruction at the beginning that says to Windows, "Hey, I expect that I'm going to be loaded starting at memory address X, because my code contains a bunch of JMP's to locations that are assumed to be relative to address X." So now Windows will try to put that DLL at location X. But if something else is already using that space, it has no choice but to put it somewhere else, call it Y. When this happens Windows has to go through the entire executable image of the DLL and replace all addresses of the form "X+n" with something that is "X+n+Y-X"... this is called rebasing and it's slow.

If you know in advance that a DLL is going to be loaded with another DLL in your own application, you can increase startup time dramatically by pre-rebasing all the DLLs so that they are non-contiguous.

Comment: That's interesting and I give you a vote just for teaching me something new.  I isolated it down to one in house dll that was taking so long to load.  I created a project that had all the same dll references but no code and it started up immediately.  On the other hand the main project has twice as many lines of code as that dll and it also starts up immediately when run on its on. (and remember, this is an issue of startup time in the ide... the project loads faster when running the compiled exe).  I don't think there's anything else to try from here but if you think of something let me know!

Comment: From those clues it makes it even more likely that rebasing the in-house DLL might help! The DLL may conflict with the address space of the IDE itself which would explain why it has to be rebased only when run under the IDE

Comment: There is another option but you won't like it. Change some or all of the DLLs so that they are late bound. This spreads the performance hit out across the program as it calls the DLLs but at a cost of complexity and the chance of getting errors that are difficult to find and fix.

Answer (score 3):

That time is probably spent initializing all the objects on the startup form. Do you have a lot of COM objects or UserControls on the startup form? They may, in turn, load other objects that they are using.

The best way to debug this is to remove one object at a time (don't worry about built-in controls, just worry about external objects) from the startup form until you figure out which one is taking the most time at startup. You can then try to speed up the launch time by optimizing the startup code in that object, or at least by deferring the creation of that object until it's actually needed.

Comment: We use a Sub Main, so the problem is well before any forms get loaded.  See my edit.

Comment: Ah. I'll add another answer, but I'm going to leave this here because it might help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Ok, so how would I know what address to rebase them at?  Is using randomly generated bases okay to do as shown here?: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/281/generate-a-dll-base-address/

I tried rebasing the dll that takes so long, but it didn't make a difference.  When I get time I may try rebasing them all and see what happens.

Comment: Check out [this old article from Dr. Dobbs](http://drdobbs.com/184416272). I can't remember the details, but you might consider using [LoadLibrarySpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301686.aspx) or something similar to see if there are relocations going on.

Comment: See also [ListDLLs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) which tells you what DLLs are loaded and at what address... if the address of any DLL doesn't match the address that DUMPBIN tells you it should be it, it got relocated!

Answer (score 0):

No way to tell from here every situation is unique.

Could be any or all. Last time I had to deal with someone elses VB code  a FormLoad ran a function in a .bas file which set up about twenty records sets...

Aside from really rough measures measuring performamnce in debug is iffy, for VB6, it's even more so as it's interpreting.

You could get a profiling tool, google VB6 Profiling tool.

Or you could add a noddy logger. Bit of code that opens a file appends a time stamped entry to it. Then start whapping calls to it in your code ( don't leave them in when you deploy..)

If you suspect it's formloads, add event handlers for your forms (Load, activate, etc) if they aren't there, and add some dummy code to stick a debug on (or a call to your noddy logger).

This is the important bit.
Optimisation 101

Don't guess! 
Stick a log call in all your major methods, look at what you are being told then drill into it. Add more calls, do more profile analysis, until you have a clear picture of what's going on.

One optimisation at a time, and bench mark it against your base figures, make sure the conditions are the same, that your loop is much faster with 10 records than 10,000 isn't that useful unless you didn't need the other 9990...

It's very easy to break your code when optimising, so have some tests ready to make sure you haven't made it come up with the wrong answer really quick.

Choose your targets, don't spend a week shaving off 1 clock cycle off a function that only gets run once a decade.

And above all unless you find the 9990 records youu didn't need type problem, remember optimisation is a trade off. For instance if all your forms are auto instantiated on running the app and you defer them until say a menu item is selected. At the moment that's a startup delay followed by real quick, deferring, will give yo a quicker start but the function will take longer. Deferring and caching will add complexity to your program.

Also it's very easy for one optimisation to conflict with another, so you load everything so it's there ready, but everything else you do from there is slow because you used up most of your available memory....

HtHs

Comment: Reread this line carefully: "So I hit F8 to start at the beginning and I realize that a significant portion of that startup time is actually between the time I hit F8 and the time it highlights the very first line of code."  I know how to optimize code... my problem is optimizing the part that's not code.

Comment: You do? Why you did you ask us how long the piece of string is then? If you know how to optimise, why would you ask someone who can't see your code where they'd GUESS the issues might be. It's all code. Some of it was written by the IDE based on what they guys wrote it thought you wanted based on what you told it. First line of code...

Comment: To your 1st question: Yes I do.  To your 2nd Question: Well... your 2nd question makes little sense to me so I don't know what to say.  To the 3rd question which you incorrectly ended with a period: Read the comments to the post I marked as the answer and you may understand better.

Comment: I ended the question with a period? Oh well that explains it then.

Answer (score 0):

This is a super-late answer and not sure if it's still relevant. As the author of large dll's and ocx's, I've run into this problem as well. My only take on it is that I believe it has to do with the registering of the public classes and that they are to be redirected through the VB6 debug library. When the application has finished, it does still take some time to return to the IDE, however, not nearly as long. Probably because it doesn't take as much to delete the registry entries as it does to add them. This is why your dll has the performance issue and not your large exe.